# How to get last element with id top pos in javascript jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Console log that [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iHC1.png)

Im tryed this for my script but that didnt work

```
var sectionElement = $(Section).find('.new-element-wrapper');
var isFirstElement = sectionElement.length == 0;
var lastElementTopOffset = sectionElement.last().offset() ? sectionElement.last().offset().top : 0;
var topOffset = isFirstElement ? '50px' : 'calc(5px + ' + lastElementTopOffset + 'px)';

const dropdownContainer = $('<div>', {
  class: 'new-element-wrapper',
  css: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: topOffset,
    left: '6%',
    width: '88%',
  }
});

console.log('Section:', Section);
console.log('sectionElement:', sectionElement);
console.log('isFirstElement:', isFirstElement);
console.log('lastElementTopOffset:', lastElementTopOffset);
console.log('topOffset:', topOffset);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.